# What is the most efficient way of whitelisting at this moment in solidity?

Tags: solidity, gas, merkle

Normal whitelisting setter functions are the most basic ones, I came across two more ways, Merkle Tree and signature-based whitelisting.

The question I had is:

1. Are the gas usage differences among them significant?
2. Inside the Merkle tree method, can I add more addresses to the whitelist in the future, as it will alter the root hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I came across was the Merkle proof system. The major reason is on-chain security + lesser gas usage.
Signature-based whitelisting is more vulnerable to attacks and the standard setter function whitelist is too expensive.
So the answers would be:

1. Yes if planned properly, then you can save a lot of gas fees inn Merkle tree system.
2. Yes we can add addresses later, but this should be done in bulk, coz there will be a transaction every time we change the root hash.

Share your perspective. For now, I am marking this as the answer.